# JavaScript: Converting Array to Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, object

I am trying to convert an array to an object, and I'm almost there.

Here is my input array:

```
[ {id:1,name:"Paul"},
  {id:2,name:"Joe"},
  {id:3,name:"Adam"} ]
```

Here is my current output object:

```
{ '0': {id:1,name:"Paul"},
  '1': {id:2,name:"Joe"},
  '2': {id:3,name:"Adam"} }
```

Here is my desired output object:

```
[ {id:1,name:"Paul"},
  {id:2,name:"Joe"},
  {id:3,name:"Adam"} ]
```

Here is my current code:

```
function toObject(arr) {
  var rv = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i)
    if (arr[i] !== undefined) rv[i] = arr[i];
  return rv;
}
```

Comment: Your desired output is an invalid json

Comment: The desired format is not supportd in ECMA5, each object must have an identifier, like in your current output

Comment: The question is why do you need your data in such form?

Comment: Just one question. Why ?:)

Comment: sorry I updated my desired output format, please check now

Comment: Your input and desired output is the same.

Comment: @making3 whoops sorry you're right now, i figured it out

Comment: Just -1ed, because output=input. Question does not make sense. Please close/remove question if it's not relevant any more

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't do that.

```
{ {id:1,name:"Paul"},
  {id:2,name:"Joe"},
  {id:3,name:"Adam"} }
```

Is not a valid JavaScript object.

Objects in javascript are key-value pairs.  See how you have `id` and then a colon and then a number? The `key` is `id` and the number is the `value`.

You would have no way to access the properties if you did this.

Here is the result from the Firefox console:

```
{ {id:1,name:"Paul"},
  {id:2,name:"Joe"},
  {id:3,name:"Adam"} } 
SyntaxError: missing ; before statement
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the objects require a key/value pair, you could create an object with the ID as the key and name as the value:

```
function toObject(arr) {
  var rv = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i)
    if (arr[i] !== undefined) rv[arr[i].id] = arr[i].name;
  return rv;
}
```

Output:

```
{
    '1': 'Paul',
    '2': 'Jod',
    '3': 'Adam'
}
```

Comment: @Paul now you're messing with us.  Your input and output formats are identical!