# Convert JS array into an object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I found some similar threads here, but not an answer really fitting to my question. Using Javascript I would like to convert an array to an object. Given the following array:

```
[{id:1,name:"aa"},{id:2,name:"bb"},{id:3,name:"cc"}]
```

I would like to attain something like this:

```
{1:{name:"aa"},2:{name:"bb"},3:{name:"cc"}}
```

What would be the fastest/shortest way? Considering I might have 1000 items in my array, how can I achieve this result in an efficient way ?

Comment: So you have JSON, or do you have an array ?

Comment: [There is no JSON in your question](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: What's the point in converting a set of objects, accessible by numerical index, into a slightly differently structured set of objects, in the same order, accessible by numerical index?

Comment: [This question is a duplicate of this previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21146895/157247) (sadly, I can't dupehammer it, I'd already voted to close for a different reason).

Comment: hm .. then it's correct if I say I have an array of JSON objects? Sorry, I'm not yet very experienced with JS/JSON.

Comment: You have an array of objects.

Comment: JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. When you're dealing with program source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Comment: I'd recommend my answer because it will allow you to build a JSON object dynamically should your array have objects of differing size or key names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over the array with [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), take the id as the key and assign a new object to this property.

```js
var array = [{ id: 1, name: "aa" }, { id: 2, name: "bb" }, { id: 3, name: "cc" }],
    object = {};

array.forEach(function (a) {
    object[a.id] = { name: a.name };
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(object, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: using `object[a.id]` instead of `object[i]` does what I want. Thanks

Comment: This is very efficient and simple but this wouldn't account for dynamic keys, since inside your 'forEach' function you are explicitly setting the 'name' key.

Comment: @Brett84c, this was not the specification.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```
[{id:1,name:"aa"},{id:2,name:"bb"},{id:3,name:"cc"}].reduce(function(result, current) {
  result[current.id] = current;
  delete current.id;

  return result;
}, {});
```

> I guess there is no way without a loop?

Correct.

> A loop wouldn't be "slow" processing an array of 10000 objects?

Define "slow". But, yes, 10,000 objects is a lot no matter what operation you're doing to them.

### edit

You can also use [_.keyBy](https://lodash.com/docs#keyBy) and  (if you're into util libraries and functional-style programming):

```
_.chain([{id:1,name:"aa"},{id:2,name:"bb"},{id:3,name:"cc"}])
.keyBy(function(o) {
  return o.id;
})
.mapValues(function(o) {
  return _.omit(o, ['id']);
})
.value();
```

Comment: `reduce` offers nothing of substance here, and introduces complexity (remembering to return the accumulator, which doesn't actually change). Which invites bugs, like the one in the answer. *Edit:* The one in the answer prior to the edit. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks for pointing out the return bug. However, I think in this case `reduce` is one of the more semantic choices out of the native iterators offered in ES5.

Comment: My view is that `reduce` is only a useful semantic choice when the accumulator *changes*, such as with a sum. When it doesn't (it's the same object reference the entire time), I prefer simply `forEach` closing over the target. To each their own.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, fair point

Comment: helps as well, thanks Josh. "slow" of course .. very precise :)

Comment: No problem @Rainer! :)

Answer (score -2):

you can change 1 to some other optionally.

var arrObject = [{id:1,name:"aa"},{id:2,name:"bb"},{id:3,name:"cc"}];

var jsObjectToJSONString = JSON.stringify({1: arrObject});

Comment: yes, this is not expected answer for this question, i thought of JS array object converting to JSON string.

Answer (score -2):

This is how you would do it dynamically which I would consider to be ideal if there's a chance some of those objects in the array have different names or differ in number of keys existing within (notice I added a 'number' field to each array item).

```js
var objArr = [{id:1,name:"aa", number:25},{id:2,name:"bb", number:10},{id:3,name:"cc", number:8}],
    jsonObj = {};

for (var i = 0; i < objArr.length; i++) {
  jsonObj[i] = {};
  var keys = Object.keys(objArr[i]);
  //start at '1' to ignore 'id' key
  for (var j = 1; j < keys.length; j++) {
    jsonObj[i][keys[j]] = objArr[i][keys[j]];
  }
}

console.log(jsonObj);
```

Comment: This doesn't produce the output the OP wants.

Comment: It does, but I guess it's not EXACTLY the "fastest/shortest way".  Personally, I think doing it dynamically like this is better than statically setting the "name" attribute on the object.  If the JSON changes whatsoever either in length or different key names, the "shortest/fastest way" won't work anymore.

Comment: If you look at the expected output you will see that the object has keys 1, 2, 3, whereas yours has 0,1,2. It seems the OP wants to use the `id` of the objects as property name, not their position in the array.

Comment: Ah, I see.  I could modify my code to address that but at this point, it doesn't seem like it matters.